# Python pyPdf issue downloading pdf

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm having a hard time reading a pdf from the internet into the python PdfFileReader object.

My code works for the first url, but it doesn't for the second and I don't know how to fix it.

I can see that in the first example, the url refers to a *.pdf file* and in the second url the *pdf is being returned as 'application data' in the html body*.

So I think this this might be the issue. Does anybody knows how to fix it so the code also works for the second url?

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from io import BytesIO
import requests

def test(url,filename):
  response=requests.get(url)
  pdf_file = BytesIO(response.content)
  existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

  page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)

  output = PdfFileWriter()
  output.addPage(page)

  outputStream = file(filename, "wb")
  output.write(outputStream)
  outputStream.close()


test('https://s21.q4cdn.com/374334112/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf','works.pdf')
test('https://eservices.minfin.fgov.be/mym-api-rest/finform/pdf/2057','crashes.pdf')
```

This is the stacktrace I have with the second call of the test function:

```
D:\scripts>test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\scripts\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    test('https://eservices.minfin.fgov.be/mym-api-rest/finform/pdf/2057','crashes.pdf')
  File "D:\scripts\test.py", line 10, in test
    page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 450, in getPage
    self._flatten()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 596, in _flatten
    catalog = self.trailer["/Root"].getObject()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyPdf\generic.py", line 480, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key).getObject()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyPdf\generic.py", line 165, in getObject
    return self.pdf.getObject(self).getObject()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 655, in getObject
    raise Exception, "file has not been decrypted"
Exception: file has not been decrypted
```

Comment: It appears the reply from the second link is a base64 encoded string, that I somehow have to read into the BytesIO object.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I imported PyPDF2 instead of pyPdf, so it was probably a bug.